# Cannot press any key to continue with command pause

Tags: psexec

I wrote a script to remote execute test.cmd file by PsExec.exe.

```
PsExec.exe \\IP -u administrator -p password "C:\\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.cmd"
```

Although I can run the script successfully, I cannot press any key to continue the process when it runs into command **pause**.

```
Press any key to continue . . . aaaaaa
```

The only way to keep going is press **Enter**.

Besides, if there are many lines of **Pause** or **set /p** which waits users to input, once user press **Enter**, it will affect couple lines of **Pause** or **set /p**. It really confuses me.

Answer (score 0):

Best is that you use different logic in accordance with your limitations. 
Try exchanging the Pause with a different suitable solution.

Other suggestion would be that you share your code, inputs and expectations (output is already given - the script doesn’t continue). Then someone can review the code and suggest for further steps.

Alternatively, it is also possible that you can fix it by using `Console.ReadKey()`